# Tomcat 7.0.0 CSRF filter prevents deploying war file

Tags: tomcat, csrf

Using the manager application to deploy a war file used to work for me but now consistently fails with "FAIL: Nonce mismatch. Command "/upload" was ignored."

I understand that the nonce is generated, stored in my session and used to validate the request.  I have tried removing cookies, closing the browser (Firefox) and logging in and restarting Tomcat, but this error persists and prevents me from using the manager to deploy war files.

Is it possible to change the configuration so that the CSRF filter is disabled?

Is there an alternative workaround?

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be unrelated to CSRF at all.  The partition where tomcat was running had run out of space.

The lesson is "Don't always take error messages at face value."